# With Out Search Button

Tags: vb.net

MS Visual web Developer:

Search button in my web form when clicked will do a lot of functions. But for attaining below mentioned one,where should I place my code instead of Search Button.

After typing the text (or while typing ) in the text box, Search function must run.[Without clicking search button or even enter key]

Thanks

Comment: use textbox textchanged event..or better you can go with jquery..Most of the search nowadays is done in jquery only..

Comment: With out clicking the enter key( when textchanged event is used ,I have to click enter)

Comment: Thats why i told you,If you want to things happen in live then use jquery

Answer (score 0):

```
Public Class Form1
    Dim words As New List(Of Object)(New String() {"apple", "banana", "berry", "cashew", "lemon", "mango", "peanut"})

    Private Sub RefreshList()
        lstword.Items.Clear()
        lstword.Items.AddRange(
            words.Where(
                Function(word) word.ToString().Contains(txtSearch.Text)
                ).ToArray()
            )
    End Sub

    Private Sub txtSearch_TextChanged(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles txtSearch.TextChanged
        RefreshList()
    End Sub

    Private Sub Form1_Load(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Me.Load
        RefreshList()
    End Sub
End Class
```